# Trying to build hello world in Vaadin connecting to my Domino Server

Tags: vaadin, lotus-domino

I created a basic Vaadin application then added my Domino Jar files.

When I run the application, I get 
[com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lotus/domino/NotesException]

I've read a bunch of articles that talk about using OSGI etc.  Isn't there a simple way to access Domino data from Vaadin without all the plug-ins etc?  If not can someone explain why?

**This is the calling code**

```
package com.lms.helloDomino;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.lms.service.StarService;
import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

import lotus.domino.NotesException;

/**
 * This UI is the application entry point. A UI may either represent a browser window 
 * (or tab) or some part of an HTML page where a Vaadin application is embedded.
 * <p>
 * The UI is initialized using {@link #init(VaadinRequest)}. This method is intended to be 
 * overridden to add component to the user interface and initialize non-component functionality.
 */
@Theme("mytheme")
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {

        StarService myStarService = null;

        try
        {
            myStarService = new StarService();
            myStarService.openStarDB();
        } catch ( Exception e1 )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

        final TextField name = new TextField();
        name.setCaption("Your Domino Name");
        name.setValue( myStarService.getNABProfile( "" ).fullName.toString() );

        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        button.addClickListener(e -> {
            layout.addComponent(new Label("Thanks " + name.getValue() 
                    + ", it works!"));
        });

        layout.addComponents(name, button);

        setContent(layout);
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

**Here is the domino code**

```
package com.lms.service;


import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.Session;
import lotus.domino.NotesFactory;


public class StarService
{

    public static Session   notesSession            = null;

    public static Session getNotesSession()
    {
        if( notesSession == null )
            try
            {
                notesSession = NotesFactory.createSession( "testHostServer", "testUser", "testPassword" );
            } catch ( NotesException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return notesSession;
    }

    public StarService() throws NotesException
    {
        System.out.println( "Begin StarService Constructor" );

        // Setup the notes connectivity
        getNotesSession();
        System.out.print( getNotesSession().getUserName() );
        System.out.println( "End STARService Constructor" );
    }


}
```

Comment: May be DAS? Domino Access Service -> REST json

Comment: Could you please provide the code to reproduce the problem?  For all we know, this could as be just a problem with the build.

Comment: I added the code.  FYI, I have several standalone java programs that use the same STARService code just fine.  It's when trying to use it with Vaadin is when it throws that error.

I have both ncos and notes jar files on the build path as I do with the other programs.

Comment: You should be able to run your Vaadin app without other fancy containers, frameworks or plugins, but build path is not necessarily equal to run-time path... How are you running your app, and are these dependencies in the classpath during execution? `NoClasDefFoundError` usually means that some class used in the app, which were present during compilation, can not be loaded at runtime.

Comment: And i don't believe, that vaadin is a factor here.  Vaadin is most likely not actively preventing the loading of that jar.  But your build config could.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a build path issue.  A big thank you to Karsten Lehmann from mindoo.de who helped me figure this out.

I didn't realize when running an Apache web server which serves up the Vaadin application, required my Domino .jar files on it's build path as well.  He showed my how to add the .jar files to Apache's as follows:

Double click the Apache server under the servers tab

Click the Open Launch Configuration

Click the Class Path Tab

Highlight User Entries and Add External Jar files.

I've been looking for this off / on for a year now.  Can't believe it's finally working!!!